# Using gregexpr and accessing elements

Tags: regex, r

So, I used `gregexpr`, and in return I got a list back:

```
b <- gregexpr(a[1],vec)
```

Now, when I view b, it is:

```
  > b
   [[1]]
   [1] 3 9
  attr(,"match.length")
   [1] 3 3
   attr(,"useBytes")
   [1] TRUE
```

Now, what I wish to do is, access the elements 3 and 9 and store them in another variable.
However, the commands

```
b[1]
b[[1]]
```

All of them display the same. What can I do to basically access only the first row elements, i.e. 3 and 9?

Comment: `as.vector(b[[1]])` will drop all attributes so you get 3 and 9.

Comment: `indices <- unlist(b)` and then `indices[[1]]` will work

Answer (score 1):

`b[[1]]` is what you want. What you are also seeing are attributes for the object. You can probably understand this more clearly by looking at the output of `str(b)`.

Relevant reading is in `? attributes` and [The R Language Definition #Attributes](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Attributes).

Answer (score -1):

```
lista <- gregexpr(pattern = ",", "123,56,89,")
lista[[1]][1:3]
```

Console: [1]  4  7 10

```
lista[[1]][1]
```

Console:[1] 4